# Exporting UltraExpandableGroupBox default expansion indicator

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I am using a UltraExpandableGroupBox in my WinForms application. And I am using the Office2003 style with it. However, I would like to reverse the Expanded and Collapsed Indicator images used.  I tried to export the images from the .isl file, but these images don't seems to be among the images exported. How do I access these images?

Answer (score 0):

When the ViewStyle property for the **`UltraExpandableGroupBox`** control is set to the `GroupBoxViewStyle.Office2003` the Expanded/Collapsed indicator uses an embedded bitmap.
Code below demonstrates how this bitmap can be obtained from the assembly on the runtime and can be used to reverse the current Expanded/Collapsed indicators:

```
private void ReverseImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var imageName = "GroupBox.ExpansionIndicator_Chevron.bmp";
    System.IO.Stream stream = typeof(UltraExpandableGroupBox).Module.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(typeof(UltraExpandableGroupBox), imageName);

    if (stream != null)
    {
        // The source bitmap has 7x10px size. 
        var image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
        // Converting the image to 16x16 pixels
        ultraExpandableGroupBox1.ExpansionIndicatorExpanded = ResizeImage(image, 16, 16);
        // Rotation
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(image))
        {
            bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
            image = bmp.Clone() as Image;

            // Exporting bitmap to a file
            bmp.Save(@".\" + imageName, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        }                
        ultraExpandableGroupBox1.ExpansionIndicatorCollapsed = ResizeImage(image, 16, 16);
    }
} 

public static Image ResizeImage(Image image, int new_height, int new_width)
{
    var dest = new Bitmap(new_width, new_height);
    var g = Graphics.FromImage(dest);
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
    g.DrawImage(image, (dest.Width - image.Width)/2, (dest.Height-image.Height)/2);
    return dest;
}
```

> Exported to a file the Expanded/Collapsed indicator bitmap looks like on the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with simple [DrawFilter](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/win-draw-filter). Set to your UltraExpandableGroupBox DraFilter property like this:

```
this.myUltraExpandableGroupBox.DrawFilter = new MyDrawFilter(expandedIndicator, collapsedInidcator);
```

Then create a new class named `MyDrawFilter` and let it inherit `IUIElementDrawFilter`. Your draw filter class may look like this:

```
    public class MyDrawFilter : IUIElementDrawFilter
    {
        Image expandedIndicator;
        Image collapsedIndicator;
        public MyDrawFilter(Image expandedIndicator, Image collapsedInidcator)
        {
            this.expandedIndicator = expandedIndicator;
            this.collapsedIndicator = collapsedInidcator;
        }
        public bool DrawElement(DrawPhase drawPhase, ref UIElementDrawParams drawParams)
        {
            if (drawParams.Element is GroupBoxExpansionIndicatorUIElement)
            {
                // if groupbox is expanded change the image with one provided in the constructor
                // as expandedIndicator
                if ((drawParams.Element.Control as UltraExpandableGroupBox).Expanded)
                {
                    (drawParams.Element.ChildElements[0] as ImageUIElement).Image = this.expandedIndicator;
                }
                // else gropbox is collapsed change the image with one provided in the constructor
                // as collapsedIndicator
                else
                {
                    (drawParams.Element.ChildElements[0] as ImageUIElement).Image = this.collapsedIndicator;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        public DrawPhase GetPhasesToFilter(ref UIElementDrawParams drawParams)
        {
            // filter when GroupBoxExpansionIndicatorUIElement should be drawn. This element has
            // one child UIElement of ImageUIElement type. This UIElement holds the expansion
            // indicator image.
            if (drawParams.Element is GroupBoxExpansionIndicatorUIElement)
            {
                // we return BeforeDrawChildeElements in order to be able to change the image
                return DrawPhase.BeforeDrawChildElements;
            }

            return DrawPhase.None;
        }
    }
```